# JetBrains Rider - errors when connecting to on-prem TFS

Tags: tfs, version-control, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am trying to connect latest version (2019.3.4) of Rider to TFS (on premise, TFS 2010).

I went through the steps in their community support (https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000335099-How-to-use-Visual-Studio-s-TFV%D0%A1-local-workspace-in-Rider), and got stuck on the step #6.

> Go to VCS -> TFVS -> Manage Workspaces, select your server, and press "Reload workspaces"

I am getting the following error when clicking reload:

[image]

If I try to click 'Edit' button, I get a different error:

[image]

When I try to view file history, I get this warning

> 13:50 Problems while loading file history: HTTP 401 Unauthorized

**Rider never asked me to authenticate with my VCS (and I see no way of doing that)**.

What should I do to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - yes, it's a useful comment. Not an answer to my problem though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer by Cece is helpful, but does not solve the problem.

It simply turned out that I need a different plugin to Rider.

The one installed by default in recent releases is for Azure DevOps.

There is another one, called TFS - and that's the one to use.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578-tfs/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you refer to is using Visual Studio's TFVС **local** workspace, while TFS 2010 only supports **Server** workspace. **Local** & **server** workspace:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops

[Azure DevOps plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops) supports working with Git and TFVC repositories on Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015+, and support **Local** workspace only.